# Eevee bump and displacement modifiers are low resolution?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, displacement, bump

I feel like I'm doing something wrong but I have found no answers online. For some reason in Blender 2.8, bump and displacement maps are always in low resolution. The antialiasing is bad, and when I zoom out from the object it just looks like a lump of pixels.

[image]

[image]

I've tried setting my antialiasing samples to 32, anisotropic filtering is 16x, multisampling is 16 and it still looks low quality, in viewport and even after it's rendered. I won't be able to use the default textures with a normal map. I've also seen a whole lot of people having high-quality bump and displacement even before Blender 2.8 officially released (Ducky 3D for example). Any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by the library that EEVEE use:

[Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html#materials)

> ### Material
>
> #### Bump Mapping
>
> As of now, bump mapping is supported using OpenGL derivatives which are the same for each block of 2x2 pixels. This means the bump output value will appear pixelated. It is recommended to use normal mapping instead.
>
> > Tips: If you absolutely need to render using Bump nodes, render at twice the target resolution and downscale the final output.

I try some approach to resolve this problem since about 10 month ago. But there isn't a plausible solution that can be easily done without changing bump map. And 2x resolution suit my application.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but that doesnt explain how a bunch of Youtubers can use bump nodes at ease with high resolution (check Ducky 3D's eevee tutorials).

Comment: @RogueLotus4 Which tutorial? I randomly pick up one and notice the pixelated effect cause by bump map or displacement map which are not gonna happen in cycles

Comment: easy environment design, and it may be a little pixelated but mine is still nowhere near as detailed as his.